# what is best way of using password_hash and password_verify

Tags: password-hash

Using md5 (old way):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE `username`='bob' AND `password`='123456'";
```

** check the password before getting data out of the database.

Using password_hash and password_verify (new way):

```
$sql = "SELECT `password` FROM 'table' WHERE `username`='bob'";

$bool = password_verify('password_from_post_method', 'password_from_database');

if($bool) {echo "your password is right";}
```

** the data was got from database first, and then check the password out of the database.

*** I think the old way is better. Get the data out of database when I confirm the password is right.  Maybe, I use password_hash and password_verify in the wrong way.  Please give suggestion if you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: I think the BEST way may be to use actual valid SQL rather than some made up language :-) You select from a table, not from a where clause.

Comment: The second approach is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> You persist [hashed(password) **+** randomSalt]
>       in the password column of your database. Can you write the SQL as
>       you have mentioned in the approach 1, during verification ? You can not, because random generated salt is also persisted along with the password. That is why your 'new way' is
>       the way to go.